# Is it possible to have 2 HTML files on JsFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I am studying a book here and there is  a exercise that needs 2 HTML files and I want to know if its possible to have to HTML files in my JsFidle

Comment: How do the files/pages interact?

Comment: I will be using AjAX to insert external Html to the main HTML file

Comment: Well in that case, I suppose you could just have your Ajax build out your HTML file within the success function.

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe it is possible. However, You could use Plunker. It's pretty similar, but allows you to create multiple files with your name extension. Was using it the other week to have a CSV as a data source.
**[Plunker Site here](http://plnkr.co/)**

Comment: Where exactly can this be done? For what I've tried, I can not seem to find an option to add another file from the left pane listing.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/gist_response.html

*Content of the http://gist.github.com/raw/606699/fiddle.response.html will be returned with text/html MIME type if this url will be loaded http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/response.html/606699/ using Ajax request.*

```
.
```